# SMTP ERROR : 421 4.7.0 Connection refused - PHPMailer

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, phpmailer

I want to send email from the server (*ubuntu server 11.10 php version 5.3.x*) but I get an error like this :

```
2021-01-18 05:15:24     Connection: opening to mail.domain.co.id:587, timeout=300, options=array ()
2021-01-18 05:15:24     Connection: opened
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SERVER -> CLIENT: 421 4.7.0 Connection refused
2021-01-18 05:15:24     CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO reporting
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SERVER -> CLIENT:
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SMTP ERROR: EHLO command failed:
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected
2021-01-18 05:15:24     Connection: closed
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2021-01-18 05:15:24     SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer wiki/Troubleshooting
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

in this my *php* code :

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
// Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer();
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                                       // Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'mail.domain.co.id';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'donotreply@domain.co.id';              // SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'password';                             // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                                  // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('donotreply@domain.co.id', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('fajar.a@domain.co.id', 'Joe User');      // Add a recipient

// Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                        // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
} else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
}

?>
```

With the same *php* code, I try to run this code in localhost and success. FYI I'm developing a application notification using email and I try to send many email while developing, is there any problem in server or something block my *SMTP* Connection in the server?

Thanks for kindly help

Comment: I am also having the same challenge on my side.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort this out for GMAIL today still. You are supposed to add your app as a secure app on **Gmail > Manage Your Google Account > Security > App Passwords**
Its going to give you a 16 character password.

Before accessing App Passwords **you need to setup 2-Step Verification** for that Gmail account, for more on this check out > https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833

This is for GMAIL.
Kind regards,
Warui.